# Why bump node giving stretched results

Tags: node-editor

I have a leaf texture and add some bump node. When i render the image is stretched. Any suggestion or help with the bump nodes whats going wrong.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a single ngon with 1646 vertices.

[image]

Not great topology in my opinion. On a polygon like that you're more likely to find UV mapping errors or inconsistencies.

For a simple object like your leaf, you don't need to have so many vertices. You can use a single plane and have the alpha channel define the outline.

Here's the same leaf using only four vertices:

[image]

[image]